# How to redirect in jsp using SQL queries?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, redirect

Actually I making a forum when users writes his/her question after submitting that post, It redirects to saving database jsp page. That page is named as `post_question.jsp`.

And that `post_question.jsp` returns to my new page called as `return_thread.jsp`. Actually this page is made for the reason because i want to make that thing when user posts his/her question ..it must suppose to return this page into `show question list page`.

`For e.g:`

When user writes his questions on stackoverflow, it automatically returns a page after clicking a `Post your question` Button where user watch his question. Same as it is ..I'm making this process.

So i'm making a process something like it fetches the `id` of that question what he/she writes on the forum. But the problem is i want to redirect my page. Here you see my program:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ page language="java" import="java.sql.*" %>
<%@ page language="java" import="java.util.Date" %>
<%@ page language="java" import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat" %>

<%

    String question_post_date=request.getParameter("question");

try{
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/forum", "root", "1234");
    Statement st=con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from thread_question where question_dateTime='"+question_post_date+"'");
        while(rs.next()){
            String question_id=rs.getString("question_id");
            response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8072/forum_website/showThread.jsp?id="+question_id);
    }
}
catch(Exception e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
%>
```

But now I'm struggling here actually. There you could see ..it is a bed method to redirect a page. I get Stuck here.. Can you please help me?

***Surely, Help would be appreciated!!***

Comment: Basically what is your need? What have you tried so far?

Comment: As you can see into my codes, I'm redirecting my page but my redirecting process is inside `while(rs.next()){` ..so basically you could estimate it... that this is a bad method to redirect ..it may stands a problem while writing question into a forum. What should i do here?? Can you help me here?

Comment: in jsp this is the simple method of redirection. As per your question there are three steps one user open a page to post question, in back-end one page handled database process and third one shows all questions list right?

Comment: `Yes`.. But here i'm using `parameter` for url... `showThread.jsp?id="+question_id` have a look into my code.. and when i write my url outside the `try-catch` block, my `question_id` variable makes a stand for the biggest problem. you could see as well

Comment: Firts of all you need to modify your sql query to get the data from database. `"select * from thread_question where question_dateTime='"+question_post_date+"'` this query fetching all those question which posted on a specific data, due to this all questions get fetched. you need to use any unique id for each question, this will be easier to you to perform task accordingly.

Comment: I know.. what you're trying to say, But i need to fetch a `unique ID` to return the place of that question. This is what i'm using here to fetch that `unique id`. That's why i'm using here a date..

Comment: Confused! What is the role of above code in your question?

Comment: Okay you see in below `while loop` there have a variable named as `question_id`... OKAY~ hm.. Now i want to use that variable outside the `Catch-block`..? How to use it? Simple... I'm using a `final` keyword.. But it is not working.. any other way?

Comment: Dear in above code when while loop get execute you only first question id get redirect and execution of code get breake. If you want to use redirection out of try block as well as while loop you can only redirect last question id, getting?

Comment: Yes.. this is what i'm saying.. now redirect is necessarily to me.. Any idea how to redirect it outside the catch block... It uses a variable inside `while loop` and i don't want to break my code. So i want to redirect it outside the catch-block? any idea?

Comment: Why are you redirecting? Just add all redirected page's code in while loop, I think this will solve your problem :)

Comment: No... It'll break.. it's a wrong method to redirect...

Comment: I am not telling for redirect. Suppose there are 1000 result in resultset, then you want to redirect 1000 times :-O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `while` to `if` and add `return;`.  Why?  Because you can only do one redirect, so using a `while` is a waste of resources and could probably also break the redirect.  And if there is any code after the redirect that would print to the response you want to `return` before that to stop execution after the redirect attempt.

```
    ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from thread_question where question_dateTime='"+question_post_date+"'");
    if(rs.next())
    {
        String question_id=rs.getString("question_id");
        response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8072/forum_website/showThread.jsp?id="+question_id);
        return;
    }
```

Always use `if(rs.next())` rather than `while(rs.next())` when the SQL query can only return one row, and always make sure the SQL query can only return one row when you expect it to only return one row.

Also the blank lines between your opening `%>` and closing `<%`s at the top of the page might prevent the redirect from being able to happen (i.e. it might set the headers and begin writing to the response). Try removing the blank lines.  You might also consider just moving your imports to the bottom of the file, because Java doesn't care where you put them.  But if you put them at the bottom, then whitespace between the `%>` and `<%`s will not set the headers prior to your redirect attempt like it might at the top.

Or, even better yet, make this a Servlet rather than a JSP and you won't need to resort to anything like that. Code like this accessing the database should be in a Servlet anyway.